# DB Connection time out while using AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-integration, spring-batch

When I try to use AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter the writer seems to do nothing. After processor process all the records and put in the chunk the writer is doing nothing and connection is timed out. Below is my configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class EmployeeJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public EmployeeJobConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job employeeJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("employeeJob")
                .start(employeeJobStep1())
                .listener(executionListener())
                .build();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public Step employeeJobStep1() throws Exception {
        return ((SimpleStepBuilder<Employee, EmployeeResult>) stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .allowStartIfComplete(allowRestart)
                .<Employee, Future<EmployeeResult>>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(employeeJobReader())
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Employee> employeeJobReader(){
        RepositoryItemReader<Employee> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.setRepository(employeeService.getRepository());
        reader.setPageSize(chunkSize);
        reader.setMethodName("findAll");
        reader.setSort(getSortMap(ASC, "employeeID"));
        return reader;
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, Future<EmployeeResult>> asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception{
        AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, EmployeeResult> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(employeeProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
        asyncItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }


     /**
     * Job Processor Method
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Employee, EmployeeResult> employeeProcessor() {
        return new EmployeeProcessor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExecutor-");
        return executor;
    }



    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Future<EmployeeResult>> asyncItemWriter() throws Exception{
        AsyncItemWriter<EmployeeResult> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(employeeJobWriter());
        asyncItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<EmployeeResult> employeeJobWriter() {
        return new EmployeeJobWriter();
    }
```

I'm getting the following exception.

2018-08-31 14:00:36 ERROR [AsyncExecutor-1] c.p.c.i.b.e.EmployeeErrorHandler - Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: springHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
Error Code: 0
Query: ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=ProcessError )
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException: 
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: springHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
Error Code: 0

Comment: Is it really taking that long to get through all of your items?  The `AsyncItemWriter` will block on a `Future.get()` call until it returns or times out so if you have one item in the bunch that is holding things up, that could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to deal with the `Future` type when using `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter`. These components will handle asynchronous processing/writing transparently, so you, as a end user, can use them as regular processors/writers without having to deal with low level concurrency constructs.

For example:

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Employee, EmployeeResult> asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception{
    AsyncItemProcessor<Employee, EmployeeResult> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
    asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(employeeProcessor());
    asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
    return asyncItemProcessor;
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<EmployeeResult> asyncItemWriter() throws Exception{
    AsyncItemWriter<EmployeeResult> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
    asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(employeeJobWriter());
    return asyncItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step employeeJobStep1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .allowStartIfComplete(allowRestart)
            .<Employee, EmployeeResult>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(employeeJobReader())
            .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
            .writer(asyncItemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: If I remove the Future<> I get  the following error in my AsyncProcessor and AsyncWriter. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncItemProcessor<Employee,EmployeeResult> to ItemProcessor<Employee,EmployeeResult>

Comment: AsyncItemProcessor<I, O> implements ItemProcessor<I, Future<O>> which is mismatching with  ItemProcessor<I, O> interface.